# How much processing time for non-Chinese EB5 Investors?

Tags: united-states, immigration, investment

[This](https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/) page mentions that the Processing time for Immigrant Petition by Alien Investor (I-526) at Immigrant Investor Program Office is:

(1) 54 Months to 75 Months for China - mainland born investors

(2) 31.5 Months to 60 Months    All other areas

I am from India, does this mean that I have to wait for at least 31.5 months to get an approval? What does it mean for some investor from Netherlands? Does he have to wait for at least 31.5 months as well, like me?

Also, why is the processing time different for Chinese nationals? I mean this is not a waitlist, is this? This is not a green card queue right? This is simply about processing regardless of any country cap. Country cap comes after the processing and approval.

Edit: I am merging another question as well. What makes processing times different? Just select "Petition for Alien relative" I-130 and you will see a variety of ranges for different categories. What makes them vary?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Expatriates. SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have posted the question there. Thanks!

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21100/how-much-processing-time-for-non-chinese-eb5-investors

Answer (score 1):

All bets are off at the moment.

The State Department completely shut down its visa processing operations for many months during the COVID-19 outbreak except for "life or death situations" (their words, not mine).

It is slowly ramping up its operations at the moment, but has a huge backlog and shifting priorities from week to week from above.

It is basically impossible to make a meaningful estimate at this point.